# Partition a graph into subgraphs such that a partition contains up to X number of a particular node type

Tags: graphs, partitions

I have a DAG graph which contains two types of nodes, A and B.

I am looking for a graph partitioning algorithm that can partition a graph in sub-graphs such that each sub-graph contains up to X number of node type B. For example, given this graph, I need to partition it topologically such that each sub-graph contains up to 3 of node type B. I want to minimize the number of partitions. So I always try to have 3 blue nodes in each partition.

Would hypergraph partitioning be suitable for this and assign each blue node a weight (for example 1) and say each partition have a maximum weight of 3?

[image]

The solution to this would look like this graph which has been partitioned to 3 sub-graph each containing up to 3 of node type B.

[image]

Comment: How is the topological partitionning relevant to your problem? Did I miss something? Also what is the constraint on the partition that stops you from creating subgraphs that contain any 3 type B nodes and any number of type B nodes?

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this question before here ...

Comment: This question seems to have been re-posted.

Comment: You deleted [your prior post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/145500/755) and re-posted it.  Please don't do that.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you can issue a bounty (once you have participated more).  Re-posting loses the feedback and questions that were left in the comments.  I see that last time someone asked a similar question: they asked what restrictions there are on the partitioning.  I still don't see any specification of the restrictions on partitioning in this question; why can't we pick any group of 3 blue nodes and put them in their own partition?

Comment: What does "partition it topologically" mean?  Right now I don't see any way that the graph structure (the edges) influences which partitions are allowed.  As such, I suspect you have not specified clearly all of your constraints.  Please [edit] your question to clarify the problem.